Convolution with scalar value
What would be the convolution of u(t) with (-1+2u(t))?mainly what I want to know is how the scalar part should be dealt in convolution?


Convolution is just an integral right?
Also, a constant can be factored out of an integral.
$$ \int (c*f(x)) = c * \int f(x) $$

So just integrate u(x) and multiply by -1 for that part of the problem.
All of that just comes from the definition of convolution and basic rules for integrals.  Reviewing those things will make doing problems related to convolution a lot easier going forward.

The photo shows the explicit calculation of the convolution, the graphs of the individual functions to be convolved and the result:

